# How can I make this Python file scan faster?

Tags: python, file, optimization

EDIT: Python 2.7.8

I have two files.  p_m has a few hundred records that contain acceptable values in column 2.  p_t has tens of millions of records in which I want to make sure that column 14 is from the set of acceptable values already mentioned.  So in the first while loop I'm reading in all the acceptable values, making a set (for de-duping), and then turning that set into a list (I didn't benchmark to see if a set would have been faster than a list, actually...).  I got it down to about as few lines as possible in the second loop, but I don't know if they are the FASTEST few lines (I'm using the [14] index twice because exceptions are so very rare that I didn't want to bother with an assignment to a variable).  Currently it takes about 40 minutes to do a scan.  Any ideas on how to improve that?

```
def contentScan(p_m,p_t):
    """ """
    vcont=sets.Set()

    i=0
    h = open(p_m,"rb")
    while(True):
        line = h.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        i += 1
        vcont.add(line.split("|")[2])
    h.close()

    vcont = list(vcont)
    vcont.sort()

    i=0
    h = open(p_t,"rb")
    while(True):
        line = h.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        i += 1
        if line.split("|")[14] not in vcont:
            print "%s is not defined in the matrix." %line.split("|")[14]
            return 1
    h.close()

    print "PASS All variable_content_id values exist in the matrix." %rem
    return 0
```

Comment: What is the version of Python you are using?

Comment: Maybe a dict (which is a hashmap, isn't it?) with acceptable values as the keys and just a null value would have faster native access?  Is python iterating over the acceptable-list, whereas it is could just have direct access to it as a dict?

Comment: Why are you using `i`?

Comment: I don't know what type of data you have, but perhaps throwing it into a SQL database would help speed things up too.

Comment: .. you might want to try removing your `vcont = list(vcont)` and `vcont.sort()` lines..

Comment: @thefourtheye This is actually the output from a db, after it can be potentially mangled by humans.  This process is the last in the chain of custody.  And version is 2.7.8 (updated the question; thanks)

Comment: @DSM but those are only executed once.... not millions of times.

Comment: Oh, @thefourtheye good call.  i isn't used; it was a copy-paste remnant.  I'll yoink that out and save a cycle.

Comment: @Chris: tell you what -- why don't you try it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for membership in a `set` of a few hundred items is **much** faster than checking for membership in the equivalent `list`.  However, given your staggering 40-minutes running time, the difference may not be that meaningful.  E.g:

```
ozone:~ alex$ python -mtimeit -s'a=list(range(300))' '150 in a'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.56 usec per loop
ozone:~ alex$ python -mtimeit -s'a=set(range(300))' '150 in a'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0789 usec per loop
```

so if you're checking "tens of millions of times" using the set should save you tens of seconds -- better than nothing, but barely measurable.

The same consideration applies for other very advisable improvements, such as turning the loop structure:

```
h = open(p_t,"rb")
while(True):
    line = h.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    ...
h.close()
```

into a much-sleeker:

```
with open(p_t, 'rb') as h:
    for line in h:
        ...
```

again, this won't save you as much as a microsecond per iteration -- so, over, say, 50 million lines, that's less than one of those 40 minutes.  Ditto for the removal of the completely unused `i += 1` -- it makes no sense for it to be there, but taking it way will make little difference.

One answer focused on the cost of the `split` operation.  That depends on how many fields per record you have, but, for example:

```
ozone:~ alex$ python -mtimeit -s'a="xyz|"*20' 'a.split("|")[14]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 usec per loop
```

so, again, whatever optimization here could save you maybe at most a microsecond per iteration -- again, another minute shaved off, if that.

Really, the key issue here is why reading and checking e.g 50 million records should take as much as 40 minutes -- 2400 seconds -- 48 microseconds per line; and no doubt still more than 40 microseconds per line even with all the optimizations mentioned here and in other answers and comments.

So once you have applied all the optimizations (and confirmed the code is still just too slow), try **profiling** the program -- per e.g http://ymichael.com/2014/03/08/profiling-python-with-cprofile.html -- to find out exactly where all of the time is going.

Also, just to make sure it's not just the I/O to some peculiarly slow disk, do a run with the meaty part of the big loop "commented out" - just reading the big file and doing no processing or checking at all on it; this will tell you what's the "irreducible" I/O overhead (if I/O is responsible for the bulk of your elapsed time, then you can't do much to improve things, though changing the open to `open(thefile, 'rb', HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE)` might help a bit) and may want to consider improving the hardware set-up instead -- defragment a disk, use a local rather than remote filesystem, whatever...

Comment: "though changing the open to open(thefile, 'rb', HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE) might help a bit)". really? this might be true if he'll get time machine and travel back to 80s. os level disk cache will always take care of that for you.

Comment: @iced, "always" is a **very** strong word indeed, since we know nothing at all about the OP's setup -- a remotely-mounted filesystem for example might well be configured in a way that lets a huge buffer size help **a bit**.  I'm convinced I phrased this sentence quite accurately, with the "a bit" and "might" precisely indicating the **possibility** of a **modest** benefit.

Comment: it's not fs level, it's vfs level. will be the same for net-mounted fs (samba, nfs - whatever). only possible case - system is very low on memory (naturally, heavy swap usage) plus high io same time. considering nature of question it's hardly the case. still, I got your point, though I can bet money that only change which is really needed is to remove split. sorting good-elements list by appearance frequency in typical file (or dynamically calculating it and re-sorting for each, say, 10K lines) will give better performance than set for sure as well.

Comment: @iced, I showed that lookup in a 300-items set is 45 times faster than average lookup in a list w/o the "appearance frequency" sort -- your absolute certainty that the latter can give you **two orders of magnitude** improvement is quite peculiar. I also showed that a typical split (assuming ~20 fields) takes less than 2 microseconds, so even hypothetically optimizing that away completely won't take more than a minute or two off the 40-minutes elapsed time -- not a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

The list lookup was the issue (as you correctly noticed). Searching the list has *O(n)* time complexity, where *n* is the number of items stored in the list. on the other hand, finding a value in a hashtable (this is what the python dictionary actually is) has *O(1)* complexity. As you have hundreds of items in the list, the list lookup is about two orders of magnitude more expensive than the dictionary lookup. This is in line with the 34x improvement you saw when replacing the list with the dictionary.

To further reduce execution time by 5-10x you can use a Python JIT. I personally like Pypy http://pypy.org/features.html . You do not need to modify your script, just install pypy and run:
  `pypy [your_script.py]`

Comment: Thanks for the pypy tip.  And there are actually thousands of items in the lookup.  It was foolish of me to start with a list.  Live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Made more pythony.
EDIT 2: Using set builtin rather than dict.

Based on the comments, I decided to try using a dict instead of a list to store the acceptable values against which I'd be checking the big file (I did keep a watchful eye on .split but did not change it).  Based on just changing the list to a dict, I saw an immediate and HUGE improvement in execution time.

Using `timeit` and running 5 iterations over a million-line file, I get 884.2 seconds for the list-based checker, and 25.4 seconds for the dict-based checker!  So like a 34x improvement for changing 2 or 3 lines.

Thanks all for the inspiration!  Here's the solution I landed on:

```
def contentScan(p_m,p_t):
    """ """
    vcont=set()
    with open(p_m,'rb') as h:
        for line in h:
            vcont.add(line.split("|")[2])

    with open(p_t,"rb") as h:
        for line in h:
            if line.split("|")[14] not in vcont:
                print "%s is not defined in the matrix." %line.split("|")[14]
                return 1

    print "PASS All variable_content_id values exist in the matrix."
    return 0
```

Comment: Truly peculiar and anti-idiomatic Python -- using a dict instead of a set, 5 statements to loop line by line instead of one, redundant parentheses in an `if`... not very performance-relevant, but really weird anyway.  The exact performance behavior you report is also hard to fathom unless `vcont` has **far** more than a few hundred entries (in my answer I had timed w/300) or its order as a list is somehow "truly perverse".

Comment: Well, what can I say:  I speak python with a C "accent".  I'm just glad that it works and is fast.  I _have_ been ignoring the "with" idiom.  I'll at least adopt that part to improve my accent.

Comment: Ok, @AlexMartelli, you win.  It definitely looks a lot nicer now.

Comment: @Chris why are you still using a `dict` though - you don't care about key/value pairs, just that the key exists... a `set` is ideal for that... `vcont = {line.split('|', 2)[2] for line in h}` and you're done. Limiting the split to 2 as @Alex has pointed out will save some (although not a massively significant amount of) time, by creating the minimum sized list possible that might meet the index being asked for...

Comment: Does set have O(1) time complexity, the way that dict (being a hashmap) does?  If so, then sure I could use set.  In my original solution i was using a set to make sure the good-list didn't have dupes, but naively cast the final set to a list thinking that as a simpler structure it would have faster access.

Comment: @JonClements  I just did a test of vcont={} vs. vcont=sets.Set() (using vcont.add() when adding a new element).  In 10 iterations of 1MM records, the dict version was 33.511 seconds, and the Set version was 40.751.

Comment: @Chris the `sets` module has been deprecated for donkey's years... use the builtin `set` which is written in C and not Python... (and why use `.add` instead of the set-comphrension?)

Comment: Using the built-in set (TIL!) performance becomes almost identical to using a dict.  34.001 seconds vs. 33.511 as a dict.  As for list comprehensions, I don't understand them as well as I should, and therefore avoid them in irrational fear.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what the list comprehension is doing.  But... would that all be done in memory?  The list of "good" values can be many many thousands of lines long.

Comment: @Chris it's a *set-comp* not a *list-comp*... it's doing exactly the same as a `.add()` and a loop will do, except without the function call overhead - so again, that should reduce some time (albeit it insignificantly)

Comment: Cool.  I don't understand, but I'll just trust a guy on the internet at this point.  FWIW, I did a longer comparison to {} vs. set, and they are for all intents and purposes identical.  I'm going to change it to use set, just so i don't forget that it exists.

Comment: @Chris the performance will be roughly the same when it comes to membership testing etc... however, `set`'s don't have the over head of keeping space for a value... so less memory intensive...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's not optimal at all. `split` is EXPENSIVE like hell (creates new list, creates N strings, append them to list). scan for 13s "|", scan for 14s "|" (from 13s pos) and `line[pos13 + 1:pos14 - 1]`.

Pretty sure you can make in run 2-10x faster with this small change. To add more - you can not extract string, but loop through valid strings and for each start at pos13+1 char by char while chars match. If you ended at "|" for one of the strings - it's good one. Also it'll help a bit to sort valid strings list by frequency in data file. But not creating list with dozens of strings on each step is way more important.

Here are your tests:

1. generator (ts - you can adjust it to make us some real data).
2. no-op (just reading)
3. original solution.
4. no split solution

Wasn't able to make it format the code, so here is gist.

https://gist.github.com/iced/16fe907d843b71dd7b80

Test conditions: VBox with 2 cores and 1GB RAM running ubuntu 14.10 with latest updates. Each variation was executed 10 times, with rebooting VBox before each run and throwing off lowest and highest run time.

Results:
no_op: 25.025
original: 26.964
no_split: 25.102

original - no_op: 1.939
no_split - no_op: 0.077

Though in this case this particular optimization is useless as majority of time was spent in IO. I was unable to find test setup to make IO less than 70%. In any case - split IS expensive and should be avoided when it's not needed.

PS. Yes, I understand that in case of even 1K of `good items` it's way better to use hash (actually, it's better at the point when hash computation is faster than loookup - probably at 100 of elements), my point is that split is expensive in this case.

Comment: Working char-by-char will hardly accelerate things in Python in most cases.  Can you post some **code** rather than empty verbiage so we can sink some -mtimeit teeth into your claims?-)

Comment: siiigh. ok, let me implement it.